# Appengine reverse reference problem

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

According to the docs: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling.html#References
the automatically created reverse reference object is a Query object, so there is possible iteration over it and making fetch calls.

**But**:
I have one model:

```
class User(db.Model):
   name = db.StringProperty()
   ...
```

and second model:

```
class Thing(db.Model):
    owner = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
    ...
```

And when I try to access reverse reference:

```
for thing in user.thing_set:
    ...
```

or:

```
user.thing_set.fetch(100)
```

I get an exception like this:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: '_ReverseReferenceProperty' object is not iterable
```

or like this:

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: '_ReverseReferenceProperty' object has no attribute 'fetch'
```

Am I doing something wrong or there was some change in appengine? I'm pretty sure that previously it worked like a Query. There is even an example on the docs page, that shows the same usage as mine:

```
for obj in obj1.secondmodel_set:
    # ...
```

Additionaly getting the query without reverse reference works ok:

```
things = Thing.all().filter('owner =', user)
```

Comment: Can you identify any particular circumstance that give rise to the to first exception an which give rise to the second exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods (iterating and fetch) should work. To debug, you might want to log (or print):

```
print dir(user)
[..., 'thing_set', ...]

print dir(user.thing_set)
[..., '__iter__', ... , 'fetch', ...]
```

just to see what the objects contain... and that might give you a hint of what could be going wrong.

A couple of ideas:

- You might be referencing another user class by mistake: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass.html
- Your user object is not saved.
- In windows, you have some old .pyc files in: C:\Users\YOUR USER NAME\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine